# Numerical resolution of equation with trigonometric expressions

Tags: equation-solving

I have difficulties to solve this equation :

```
NSolve[(x^3 + Sin[x]*Cos[x]) == 0, x]
```

I receive the following error message :

> This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve

**May you help me to solve this equation ?**

Comment: Are you aware you are trying to find complex-valued solutions? It works fine if you specify it for reals, doing `NSolve[..., Reals]` instead.

Comment: right. Thank you for your help. This post can be closed